# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '50' for java.sql.Time type in value '50:51:05

Tags: java, mysql, time, duration

When I try to retrieve time from MySQL and set it to a `JLabel`, it gives me an error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '50' for java.sql.Time type
>   in value '50:51:05.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Code is as follows.

```
        String sql = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ot)))"
                + " FROM attendance"
                + " WHERE department = '"+department+"'"
                + "   AND date BETWEEN '"+dateChooser1+"' AND '"+dateChooser2+"'";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rst = st.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rst.next())
        {
            String time = rst.getString(1);
            oTimeTemp.setText(time);
        }
```

Comment: There's a difference between "time" and "duration" - also, you should consider having a look at [Using prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: [time_to_sec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) takes a clock time (as in time of day). There is no hour 50 in a day.

Comment: Could you post a complete stacktrace *and* point of which line in your code the exception comes from? In any case, I think you should just use `select sum(time_to_sec(ot))) from /* etc */` and process the sum of the seconds in Java somehow.

Comment: @MarsAtomic It’s not the full explanation since MySQL time values go up to '838:59:59'.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used prepared statement . But error comes.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Is there a way that I can set 50:51:05 ?

Comment: @HansanaAthukorala There is a difference between time and duration "50:51:05" isn't a valid time

Comment: please double check your table structure and default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Here is the code,

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ot))"
            + " FROM attendance"
            + " WHERE department = '"+department+"'"
            + " AND date BETWEEN '"+dateChooser1+"' AND '"+dateChooser2+"'";
    st = con.createStatement();
    rst = st.executeQuery(sql);
    if(rst.next())
    {
            String time = rst.getString(1);
            Double dTime = Double.valueOf(time);
            int intTime = (int) dTime.doubleValue();
            String nTime = calculateTime(intTime);
            oTimeTemp.setText(nTime);
    }

private static String calculateTime(int totalSecs)
{
    int hours = totalSecs / 3600;
    int minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = totalSecs % 60;

    String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    return timeString;
}
```

Comment: Why go through all of this?  The simplest solution is to remove the `SEC_TO_TIME` conversion back, just return the total seconds, and do the conversion to a ***duration*** in the Java code.

Comment: @JimGarrison So, What you are asking?

Comment: Glad that my suggestion worked. The code could probably be further improved, for example through the use of `Duration` from java.time.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes. Thank you very much for the solution. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mysql bug , use it  as follows it would work fine:

```
 String sql = "SELECT concate(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ot))),'')"
 + " FROM attendance"
 + " WHERE department = '"+department+"'"
 + "   AND date BETWEEN '"+dateChooser1+"' AND '"+dateChooser2+"'";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// if you want to use time as label  
// you can use oTimeTemp if Date type of java.util, this have both time and date

    if(rst.next())
        {
// this Time string need to cast  in util time
           String time = rst.getString(1);  
           String time = time ;
           DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
           Date date = sdf.parse(time);
           oTimeTemp.setText(date); // in this date we have the time
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Keeps getting the error. However thanks for the answer.

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class as the first option and without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).